# How to determine the number of time steps in Modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I need to calculate the number steps to calculate a numerical method in such a way that for i=0 the time be t=tstart and for i=nsteps the time be t=tstop.

I know the real numbers tstart, tstop and dt, and to calculate the integer nsteps I use

```
nsteps = FLOOR((tstop-tstart)/dt)
```

but I'm worried, because FLOOR could be and integer minus one than I need. The following is the loop on the time:

```
DO i=0,nsteps
    t = tstart + i*dt

END DO
```

I think this is a very usual calculus, but I do not know which is the better way to do it. Maybe there is a better idea instead of a DO loop, maybe a DO WHILE loop.

Thanks in advance for yours comments.

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. The [tag:fortran90] tag is about astandard revision that is more than 30 years old - hardly "modern".

Comment: If it matters whether you have `nsteps` or `nsteps-1` then you should probably have `nsteps` as the input variable rather than `dt`.

Comment: Is really tstoputstart divisible by dt? If yes, nint() sounds like a better option. If not, you have to make some adjustments to your parameters. Change dt, make the last time step shorter, extend tstop,...

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF , That was the first that I thought, and it works, but I consider the veryreverie way more elegant to solve it. Thanks for share that idea.

Comment: All of these ways make sense. Once the code becoms general, it may be necessary to implement all of them because once you need dt to be fixed, next time you need tstop to be fixed and yeat snother day ntimes must be fixed.  You fix one or two parameters and complete the rest. What is more elegant depends on the specific needs and circumstances. In my CFD code, for example, any of those possibilities mentioned may be selected.